# Error retrieving place ID. Response code ZeroResults

Tags: google-places-api

We use the Google Places API and on 2/14/2024, we received about 100 Error retrieving place ID. Response code ZeroResults.  Does anyone have any idea what that means?

We researched a few of them that were legitimately closed businesses but, the majority of them appeared to be legitimate businesses with the correct address.

Comment: Do you have some running code that you can post that shows how you're sending your Places API request?

Answer (score 0):

That is expected to happen when places are either

- **removed** from Google Maps, for whatever reasons, or
- *converted* into *pure* Service Area Business (*location-less*) establishments, which would be done by (each) business owners via [Google Business Profile](https://www.google.com/business/).

To check whether one or the other is the case, you can use [Google Maps URLs: Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#search-action) which accepts Places IDs in the `query_place_id`. Setting `query` to something that can't be find (e.g. `%20` for a blank space) *should* ensure that if you get a result it *is* the Place ID (and not something else):

https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=%20&query_place_id=ChIJjVrE3tfBhkcR2qacmdIF9Fw

This example place is a pure Service Area Business, note how it shows on Google Maps without an address or precise location, and instead shows an (approximation) to the area they provide(d) service to.

If you are interested in retrieving pure Service Area Business via Places API, see feature request [35828187:Support service area businesses](https://issuetracker.google.com/35828187).

Note also that, although this place is *also* **permanently closed**, that *alone* is not enough of a reason for an establishment to go missing from Place **Details**; it will go missing from Place Search and Autocomplete results, just not Details.

More generally, see Places API documentation to [Save place IDs for later use](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-id#save-id), which includes recommendations for refreshing stored place IDs and handling error codes when using place IDs (`NOT_FOUND` in Places API, `ZERO_RESULTS` in the Geocoding API).